# Height 100% for deeply nested element

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a Wordpress-page with a fronpage consisting of several screens. The first of these pages contains a `background-image` which is supposed to `cover` the whole page.

It works as expected when assigning `height: 100%` to the parent-element on every level.

Since I use a page-builder-plugin (the people I create the site for want to be able to easily edit the content) the first (100% height page) is deeply nested (like `html > body > #page > #main > article > .entry-content > div > div > div > div ...`

**Is there a better alternative to set this element to 100% height?**

*Note: It has to be compatible down to IE 8*

Comment: Using ID selectors (`#id`) guarantees you'll only get one element, so you don't need anything before the most deeply nested ID, and you don't need to specify the full path.  The path you provided could be simplified to `#main > article > .entry-content div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible alternative, to get this working everywhere including IE8, is to use `viewport units` and a polyfill:

https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/1347501

```
.your-element { height: 100vh; }
```

Note: the above polyfill also requires Lea's `StyleFix` JS library:
https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree

If you want to do this without JavaScript (and I never recommend using JavaScript for basic layout), then setting `height:100%` on all your elements is the only way to go.